# Санкции - это одобрение или наказание?

Tags: заимствования

Sanctio (лат.) – освящение, подтверждение, одобрение, но почему это слово  обозначает также и наказание?

Какова история применения   "санкций"  в  двух противоположных значениях?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здесь нет противоположных значений. Санкция - это мера, некое действие, требующее разрешение или одобрения.

Отсюда два значения, отнюдь не противоположных.
1. Разрешение (начальства и т.п.) на проведение чего-либо. Больше касается права.
2. Проведение некоего действия, обычно - направленного против стороны, нарушившей какой-либо договор, моральное положение, кодекс. Это чаше используется в экономике.

Вот и все различие, по области применения: в экономике и праве.

Ни в одном значении нет ни слова "освящение", ни "запрет". "Наказание" - ну да, может быть во втором значении, но это не передает общий смысл. "Освящение" в прямом смысле присутствует только в латинском первоисточнике, но уже во французском использовании этот смысл потерян.

Лучше всего эти нюансы видны в определении значения в словаре иностранных слов:

САНКЦИЯ
    [лат. sanctio - строжайшее постановление] - 1) утверждение чего-л. высшей инстанцией, разрешение; 2) меры против нарушения официального соглашения; наказание.

http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_fwords/32429/%D0%A1%D0%90%D0%9D%D0%9A%D0%A6%D0%98%D0%AF

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, всё понятно.

Answer (score -2):

Одно из слов с корнем «сан», а именно *сан,* значит *достоинство* (суверенность во всём, в том числе, принятии односторонних решений), и также,— *начальство* или *начальствование*, что означает «дарующий начала». Наказание в этой связи представляется не серьёзным уровнем мер во взаимоотношениях стран (если вы об этом), хотя, конечно, является сопутствующим эффективным продуктом наставления на путь истинный.

Comment: Сан - это вообще из другой оперы.

Comment: Это — увертюра.